# How to stretch certain grid elements only?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I've created grid with parameters:

```
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto-fit;
    grid-template-areas: ". a ."
                         "b c d"
                         ". e .";
}
```

Since `a`,`b`, `d`, `e` are buttons and `c` is flexible table, I don't need stretching grid to window size. (I use grid just to place items in right position). Moreover, I need it to be able to go beyond the page(window) boundaries if needed, but keep the original size of all items.

What property should I use to solve this problem? Or should I use different method?

Comment: as far as I understand you are looking for an *inline-grid* - see an [**`example here`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55309569/css-grid-problem-with-background-and-wrapping/55324190#55324190) and see https://jsfiddle.net/s3mde0yg/